# Parse output of Printing Admin Scripts

Tags: batch-file, truncate

For some reason or another when I run the code below it truncates the very end of the string I am echoing at the end. Is there a way to prevent that?

```
@echo off
chdir C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US
For /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('wmic computersystem get name') do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do set "compName=%%a"
Set comp=%compName:~0,5%
Set pName=%comp%P1

For /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript prnmngr.vbs -l ^|findstr /i /b /n /c:"printer name" ^|findstr /b "6:"') do set printerName0=%%a
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript prnmngr.vbs -l ^|findstr /i /b /n /c:"printer name" ^|findstr /b "25:"') do set printerName1=%%a
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript prnmngr.vbs -l ^|findstr /i /b /n /c:"printer name" ^|findstr /b "44:"') do set printerName2=%%a

If "%printerName0%" == "6:Printer name %pName%" (
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript prnmngr.vbs -l ^|findstr /i /b /n /c:"driver name" ^|findstr /b "8:"') do set driverName=%%a
)
If "%printerName1%" == "25:Printer name %pName%" (
    For /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript prnmngr.vbs -l ^|findstr /i /b /n /c:"driver name" ^|findstr /b "27:"') do set driverName=%%a
)
If "%printerName2%" == "44:Printer name %pName%" (
    For /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript prnmngr.vbs -l ^|findstr /i /b /n /c:"driver name" ^|findstr /b "46:"') do set driverName=%%a
)
If "%printerName0%" == "6:Printer name %pName%" (
    set pDriver=%driverName:~14%
)
If "%printerName1%" == "25:Printer name %pName%" (
    set pDriver=%driverName:~15%
)
If "%printerName2%" == "44:Printer name %pName%" (
    set pDriver=%driverName:~15%
)
echo %pDriver%
pause
```

Comment: You have not shown us what the input is and what the expected output is. You do realize that all those `SET` commands are manipulating the variable.  Essentially removing characters.

Comment: Input varies. The script is looking for and setting the printer driver to a variable for a given printer. In this case of my test machine with three printers installed it should return "HP Universal Printing Driver PCL5 (v6.1.0)" instead it returns "HP Universal Printing Driver PCL5 (v6.1.0". If I echo the variable before the final set of If Checks where I set "pDriver=%driverName:~14%" I get the full "HP Universal Printing Driver PCL5 (v6.1.0)". So I think it is something within my last series of If checks.

Comment: You got so much extra code it is not even funny.  I will post you a better solution with A LOT LESS code shortly.

Comment: You do know that there is already an environmental variable named %computername%.  Not sure why you are using WMIC to get the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using my original script I was able to prevent the ) from being clipped by inserting "" around the variable being set in the final If Check and then removing them from the command I am inputting the variable into.

```
If "%printerName0%" == "6:Printer name %pName%" (
    set pDriver="%driverName:~14%"
)
If "%printerName1%" == "25:Printer name %pName%" (
    set pDriver="%driverName:~15%"
)
If "%printerName2%" == "44:Printer name %pName%" (
    set pDriver="%driverName:~15%"
)
```

Where the variable is getting used later on:

```
cscript prndrvr.vbs -d -m %pDriver%
```

No quotes are needed as the are included in the first section of code where I set the final variable name. Where as this answer does require a few more lines of code it runs faster.

The Reason For The Issue:

When ) came up in the variable string Batch was seeing it as the end of the If Check and not as an included character in the variable string. In order to retain and prevent unwanted results from the code " " must encase the variable.

Comment: I sure would like to see your whole code.  Still sounds like you are doing something wrong.  I am still not understanding why you are doing all those IF checks for the printer name to assign the printer driver. Assigning a line number to each printer name with findstr makes no sense to me either.  You should not have to do that if you use prncnfg.vbs. `cscript //Nologo //H:CScript prncnfg.vbs -g -p "%pName%" ^|findstr /i /c:"driver name"`

Comment: I still have a few more things to tie in like a statement which will reach out and download the proper driver if it is missing and a statement to default the printers to gray scale, but here is what I have so far for the entire script so far. Basically it deletes a printer, completely sanitizing computer of it and then installs the desired one. Some of out locations have two-three printers and the one we are deleting to install the new one might be in the printing manager in a random order so my If Checks account for that by check all possible places in the que. http://pastebin.com/H8k1yT9S

Comment: And just to clarify, your script worked well. I tested it with the bottom three If Checks to account for where the printer might be within the printer management, it just took longer to run. It was -a lot- smaller in byte size though so if I was super tight on resources I would use that. Its a speed vs. size thing.

Comment: Either you are not understanding what I am trying to explain or I don't understand you.  IMHO your script is doing doing more then it needs to.

Comment: I think there is a miscommunication. Your script returns all the printers and drivers. I only need to return 1 specific printer and driver and that printer could be mixed up at any position in Devices and Printers. The script you provided doesn't account for that so if I deploy it blindly (as will be the case) it might pull the wrong info. The addition If Checks account for this by creating logic to select the proper printer. When I modified your script to do this as well it ran, but was slower. Although it is light weight it wouldn't be ideal for rapid deployment push.

Comment: And I told you that if you know the printer name all you need to use is prncnfg.vbs.  Adding a number with findstr and checking all that verbose output is overkill. You are making harder to check for the correct printer.

Comment: And if you looked and learned from my FOR /F examples that use the TOKENS and DELIMS you could get rid of all the IF statement to do the substring for the driver name.

Comment: And your script will fail if the printer you are looking for is not one of the first three printers.  What I am trying to say is you are tying your hands behind your back.  Your script is not dynamic enough. While my script is telling you all the printers and drivers installed my will definitely not fail, but yours will.

Comment: Too true, we only have at max three printers in the environment, some machines have less though. I was thinking about increment it instead of just plain texting it as "8:" etc, but was too lazy to. Just seemed faster to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you are trying to do.  Was really baffled by all your extra findstr code and set commands.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

PUSHD C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US

SET I=0
For /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%G in ('cscript //Nologo //H:CScript prnmngr.vbs -l ^|findstr /i /c:"printer name"') do (
    SET /A I+=1
    SET "PRINTER.NAME[!I!]=%%I"
    For /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%J in ('cscript //Nologo //H:CScript prncnfg.vbs -g -p "%%I" ^|findstr /i /c:"driver name"') do (
        SET "PRINTER.DRIVER[!I!]=%%L"
    )
)

FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,%I%) DO (
    ECHO PRINTER %%I = !PRINTER.NAME[%%I]!
    ECHO  DRIVER %%I = !PRINTER.DRIVER[%%I]!
)
popd
pause
```

Output on my computer.

```
PRINTER 1 = Microsoft XPS Document Writer
 DRIVER 1 = Microsoft XPS Document Writer
PRINTER 2 = Fax
 DRIVER 2 = Microsoft Shared Fax Driver
PRINTER 3 = \\SERVER_NAME\WI5140-XEROX-9
 DRIVER 3 = Xerox WorkCentre 5330 PCL6
PRINTER 4 = \\SERVER_NAME\WI5101-XEROX-12
 DRIVER 4 = Xerox WorkCentre 5330 PS
PRINTER 5 = \\SERVER_NAME\WI5101-XEROX-1
 DRIVER 5 = Xerox WorkCentre 7225 PS
PRINTER 6 = \\SERVER_NAME\WI5140-XEROX-31
 DRIVER 6 = Xerox ColorQube 8870DN PS
PRINTER 7 = \\SERVER_NAME\WI5140-XEROX-15
 DRIVER 7 = Xerox Phaser 5550DN PS
Press any key to continue . . .
```

EDIT: 20170225 14:35 CST

As you have said in previous comments you are only looking for one printer driver  and I have said in previous comments you can do that with EXACTLY one FOR /F command since you already know the name of the printer. You don't need to use prnmngr.vbs to get the driver because prncnfg.vbs allows you to list the configuration for a printer and then you can use findstr to just get the driver. You know the name of the printer so you use that as your input to prncnfg.vbs to list the configuration for that printer.

```
For /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%J in ('cscript //Nologo //H:CScript prncnfg.vbs -g -p "%pName%" ^|findstr /i /c:"driver name"') do set "pDriver=%%L"
```

EDIT 20170225 15:20 CST

Lets brute force to get the driver with prnmngr.vbs since that seems to be what you want to use to get the driver.

```
Set "pName=%comp%P1"
set "flag="
For /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%G in ('cscript //nologo prnmngr.vbs -l ^|findstr /i /b /C:"printer name" /C:"driver name"') do (
    IF DEFINED flag set "pDriver=%%I" &GOTO :BREAK
    IF "%pName%"=="%%~I" SET flag=1
)
:BREAK
echo %pDriver%
pause
```

Comment: This is good, but it is slower than what I had and I'd still have to have all of my If checks to account for printer placement as I only need to grab the driver from 1 single printer and not all three. For example: I am looking for just the driver on printer ABC and on one computer it is in slot one (that is Printer 1/Driver 1) but on another it might be in slot 2 or 3. The majority of my code was to account for a roaming printer.

Comment: If you know the printer name then all you need is to use prncfg to list that printers configuration.

Comment: The full script already nabs the printer name, this portion is just to name the correct driver name so I can delete it and fully sanitize a system before installing a different printer in it's place. I'm going to mess around with the code you provided, because I think it might work since I no longer would need to use my last three If Checks to remove the line numbers from prnmngr. Give me a bit and thank you.

Comment: @HaydenB.Siegel, exactly.  You can use prncnfg.vbs to just list the configuration for the printer you want.  That is what I am doing with the nested FOR command.  All you need is that one for command to get the driver if you know the printer name already.

Comment: Still ran into the clipping at the end, but I found the issue, just not sure how to account for it. In one of the drives I have it cites a version in parentheses the closing one ")" is getting clipped out. All other characters are fine, just not the ")".

Comment: @HaydenB.Siegel, are you using delayed expansion with the variable.

Comment: @HaydenB.Siegel, you should surround your SET statement in quotes like  this to protect special characters: `set "driver=printer(pcl5)"`  Then use delayed expansion to reference it. You can then always put quotes around this variable when you need to use it.  Don't do this. `set var="printer(pcl5)"`

Comment: Oh, yeah. I probably should go back and do that for the rest of those. Thanks for the eyes on it!

Comment: The edit you made failed to return the variable pDriver instead it echoed all drivers. I used just echo %pDriver% since that is the var I am passing in the complete script. How are you passing pName and pDriver in order to get just a single return?

Comment: @HaydenB.Siegel There is no way either of the two new sets of code I provided to you will echo all drivers.

Comment: Using prncnfg.vbs should be the easiest possible solution for you.  It should not be that hard to understand how that works.  Just test this code by itself, all alone, and hard code the printer name. `cscript //Nologo //H:CScript prncnfg.vbs -g -p "Name of your printer"`.

Comment: Sorry it took a moment to get back to you I was out the last couple of days. I tried both the edit and the plain text of the driver name. The edit from EDIT 20170225 15:20 CST didn't run at all and the first solution still came back with all drivers. Idk, maybe its because I'm running them on Windows 7 Embedded? I marked this as solved using my original solution, thanks for helping me get there though! :D